# C++ [Error] no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'Vehicle' and 'const Vehicle')

Tags: c++

I have the following problem:

```
"[Error] no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'Vehicle' and 'const Vehicle')"
```

`Vehicle` being a class in my project.

This is what is giving me the error:

```
int DayLog::findWaitingPosistion(Vehicle const& v){
    if (find(waitingList.begin(),waitingList.end(),v) != waitingList.end())
        return 1;
}
```

`waitingList` is a vector of `Vehicle` objects.

Comment: In order to use `find`, you need to define an `operator==` function which will compare `Vehicle`s with each other.  This could either be a free function or a member function. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4421719/1505939) for example

Comment: So, you need an `operator==` for your vehicle type (preferrably that takes a const)

Comment: you better provide more code if you want an answer

Comment: Thanks guys for the comments. I fixed it with your suggestions. I'm still a beginner and don't know lots of stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The minimum requirements for using find is a specified [`operator==`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) function. This is what [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) uses as it iterates through the vector if it has found your type.

Something like this will be necessary:

```
class Vehicle {
    public:
    int number;
    // We need the operator== to compare 2 Vehicle types.
    bool operator==(const Vehicle &rhs) const {
        return rhs.number == number;
    }
};
```

This will allow you to use find. See a [live example here.](http://ideone.com/UrpQIr)

Answer (score 4):

The error message is pretty clear:  The compiler is looking for an operator== function that compares two vehicles.  The signature of such a method, were it to exist, would be something like

```
bool operator==(const Vehicle& first, const Vehicle& second);
```

What's not as clear is *why* this is happening.  After all, you don't use an == operator anywhere in your code!  Crummy compiler - complaining about something you didn't even do.

To understand what's happening, you have to understand the 'find' method.  This is a template method, and in C++ templates are pretty much super-fancy text find-and-replace (warning: massive simplification!).  The code for 'find' is going to be generated on-the-fly for the types that you're using right before the compiler runs.

You can check out how find is implemented [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/).  In the unlikely event that cplusplus.com ever goes offline, I've included the relevant portion below*:

```
template<class InputIterator, class T>
    InputIterator find (InputIterator first, InputIterator last, const T& val)
    {
        while (first!=last) {
        if (*first==val) return first; //<--- Notice the == operator
        ++first;
        }
    return last;
    }
```

That's where the == is coming from!  The compiler is going to automatically generate the find code for the type you've specified (vehicle).  Then when it goes to compile, that generated code tries to use an operator== but there isn't one for vehicle.  You're going to have to provide one with your vehicle class.

*Seriously though - [check out that website](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/).  It shows you how all of this stuff works.